# sql job cancel triggers failure notification

Tags: jobs

When I cancel a sql agent job running an ssis package, I get a failure email because I set up the notifications to email when the Job Fails.

Does anyone know why this is considered a 'failure'?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Because SSIS package are executed as step of type CmdExec. When you cancel this step the process being run is forced to end prematurely.  Consequently premature termination of a process is considered a failure. Behind the scene cancelling a job calls for [sp_stop_job](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms182793.aspx)

For other type of job steps in a SQL agent job for e.g. T-SQL command performing a backup, when you cancel this job it finishes the currently executing step so it is not considered a failure.

Comment: Thanks this is what I was thinking, so your answer confirmed my thinking.